# cannot run tests using maven to run my projects

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml

I am trying to run my tests but I am facing an issue where I cannot run my tests when I run the following command:
`mvn clean test`

my project contain 3 modules (see image attached):
[image]

Every module in the project contains `pom.xml` file which contains only the dependencies relevant for the module.

the main pom.xml (the reactor) is the file which run the test and control the project, and this is its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.hackeruso</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
      <module>automation-ui</module>
      <module>automation-api</module>
      <module>morpheus</module>
    </modules>

    <name>neo</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
      <testng.version>7.3.0</testng.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.6</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>${testng.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20</version>
          <configuration>
            <argLine>
              -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
            </argLine>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
              <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

when I run the command `mvn test` I am getting the following message:

```
No tests to run.
```

And this image shows where I hold my tests:
[image]

```
src/test/java/com/hackeruso/automation/ui/LoginTest
```

This is an example for my test class:
**--------------------EDIT-------------------------------------------**

```
package com.hackeruso.automation.ui;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test(dataProvider = "userDetailsProvider")
    public void loginTest(String username, String password){
        signIn(username, password);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "userDetailsProvider")
    public Object[][] userDetailsProvider(){
        return new Object[][] {
                {"user@mail.com", "*******"}
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: But I do have it is under src/test/java/com/hackeruso/automation/ui/LoginTest

Comment: I'll add it to my post under -----EDIT-----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent project has a packaging of `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. This means this is a meta-project and should not contain any source code.

What you need to do is to move the tests in any of the existing modules or create a new one for these tests. By looking at the package structure of the tests, I guess it would be `automation-ui` in your case.

Then use the following command to run the tests from all the modules

```
mvn test -am
```

Where `-am` will make all the submodules.

If you want to run tests for a single module, use

```
mvn test -pl <submodule-name>
```

Comment: My tests located under src as you can see in the last image I added to this post. 
automation-ui module only contains the logic for the project (page object model and base page but no tests would be present in this module).

Comment: The parent project should not have the `src` directory. Create a separate module for tests. The purpose of parent is to contain sub-modules.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Packaging):

> For example, a project that is purely metadata (packaging value is
> pom) only binds goals to the install and deploy phases (for a complete
> list of goal-to-build-phase bindings of some of the packaging types,
> refer to the Lifecycle Reference).

As you can see, only install and deploy phases (not test) are valid for a `pom` packaged project.

The Java code should be not there, since a `pom` project should be purely metadata.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually what I did was creating another module for testing and the main project module will contain only Metadata as @Yasin suggested, I also deleted the 'src' package from my main project module leaving it just with a pom.xml file which will manage the other modules (the reactor).
Now everything is working as expected.

Thanks!